# Wait for a button click before proceeding

Tags: javascript, html, button, wait

I have an alert pop up asking "would you like to play" and if the answer is true it runs some code. But after you click "yes" I wish for a button to be pressed, and my code continues to run without waiting for it to be pressed.

Here is what I have as Javascript:

```js
var start = confirm("Would you like to Play?");
var plays = 0;
var playerScore = 0;
var computerScore = 0;
var userChoice = ""
function choose(buttonChoice) {
    userChoice = buttonChoice;
}

while(start) {

    var pScoreDiv = document.getElementById('pScore');
    pScoreDiv.innerHTML  = playerScore;

    var cScoreDiv = document.getElementById('cScore');
    cScoreDiv.innerHTML  = computerScore;

    console.log(playerScore);
    console.log(computerScore);

    var computerChoice = Math.random();

    if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
        computerChoice = "rock";
    } else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
        computerChoice = "paper";
    } else {
        computerChoice = "scissors";
    }
}
```

```html
<button onClick="choose('rock')">Rock</button>
<button onClick="choose('paper')">Paper</button>
<button onClick="choose('scissors')">Scissors</button>
```

Comment: The best thing to do would be to make a JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/) of your game and share the link, so that people on here can have a look at it  and debug it properly for you.

Comment: Okay trying it now :)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3cuwnafz/

Comment: theres the JSFiddle file hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only listening for the confirm button to be chosen, not the buttons to be clicked on.

In the below code I have changed the `while` into a function that checks if `start` has been set, and is called when a button is clicked on.

```js
var start = confirm("Would you like to Play?");
var plays = 0;
var playerScore = 0;
var computerScore = 0;
var userChoice = ""

function choose(buttonChoice) {
  userChoice = buttonChoice;
  play();
}

function play() {
  if (start) {
    var pScoreDiv = document.getElementById('pScore');
    pScoreDiv.innerHTML = playerScore;

    var cScoreDiv = document.getElementById('cScore');
    cScoreDiv.innerHTML = computerScore;

    console.log(playerScore);
    console.log(computerScore);

    var computerChoice = Math.random();

    if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
      computerChoice = "rock";
    } else if (computerChoice <= 0.67) {
      computerChoice = "paper";
    } else {
      computerChoice = "scissors";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<button onClick="choose('rock')">Rock</button>
<button onClick="choose('paper')">Paper</button>
<button onClick="choose('scissors')">Scissors</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if (start == true) {
```

instead of

```
while (start) {
```